# IONIC: Cordova/Android. El emulador y APK instalada no leen la API REST de un dominio en http://

Tags: android, rest, cordova, ionic-framework

intento debugar la app en el emulador y en el móvil instalando la apk pero no recibo datos de la API de un dominio http:[www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com) (ej.)

- Sí los recibo vía web desde el navegador.
- he configurado el config.xml de la app dejando:

  ```
  <access origin="*" />
  <allow-navigation href="http://*/*" />
  <allow-navigation href="https://*/*" />
  <allow-navigation href="data:*" />
  <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
  <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
  <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
  <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
  <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
  <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
  ```
- He instalado el Cordova wishlist:

  ```
   $ cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist
   $ cordova prepare
  ```
- He matado android y vuelto a levantar:

  ```
   ionic cordova platform remove android
   ionic cordova platform add android
  ```
- He puesto en el archivo index.html de IONIC, la siguiente meta:

  ```
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" , content="default-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; connect-src * 'unsafe-inline'; img-src * data: blob: 'unsafe-inline'; frame-src *; style-src * 'unsafe-inline';" />
  ```

Pero ni el emulador ni la APK me devuelven los datos en la NGX-TABLE que los lee de una API situada en un dominio externo.
Me dejo algo?

Answer (score 0):

Este es un problema común en el CLI de ionic V5 el problema se debe a las politicas de CORS que google implemento

Para comprobar que es esto, prueba lo siguiente:

1. Utiliza el comando para ejecutar la app en el
   emulador/dispositivo(si es en el dispositivo debe estar conectado y
   en modo debug) `ionic cordova run android`
2. Abre google chrome y en la barra de navegación escribe la siguiente:
   [chrome://inspect/#devices](http://chrome://inspect/#devices)
3. Se mostrara la pantalla  del dispositivo con el cual estés ejecutando y también veras la consola.
4. Comentame que error te muesta

Si el problema tiene que ver con CORS

La solucion es la siguiente :

Entra al achivo

```
platforms\android\app\src\main\res\xml\network_security_config.xml
```

Modificalo hasta que lo tengas asi:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<network-security-config>
   <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="system" />
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">localhost</domain>
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">http://tudominio.com</domain>
           
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

Ahora modificamos el archivo `config.xml`

Después de la apertura de la etiqueta

```
 <platform name="android">
```

Agrega lo  siguiente

```html
<access origin="*" />
        <edit-config file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <application android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" />
            <application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" />
        </edit-config>
        <allow-navigation href="*" />
```

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución, esta publicación no es una solución al problema, puedes realizar comentario y posteriormente con la información del OP responder, revisar [answer], saludos.

Comment: Estoy a espera de su respuesta para ver el error posterior mente editare con la respuesta

Comment: @WilfredoAleman me aparecen los dispositivos sdk_gphone_x86
#EMULATOR-5554
WebView in io.ionic.starter (83.0.4103.106)
trace
Ionic App
http://localhost/home
at (0, 171)
size 1080 × 1977, me aparece como issue en chrome "Indicate whether to send a cookie in a cross-site request by specifying its SameSite attribute"

Comment: eh modificado la respuesta. prueba y me cuentas

Comment: @WilfredoAleman - hechos los pasos, arranco otra vez y me devuelve Chrome "Because a cookie's SameSite attribute was not set or is invalid, it defaults to SameSite=Lax, which prevents the cookie from being sent in a cross-site request. This behavior protects user data from accidentally leaking to third parties and cross-site request forgery.

Resolve this issue by updating the attributes of the cookie:
Specify SameSite=None and Secure if the cookie should be sent in cross-site requests. This enables third-party use.

Comment: @WilfredoAleman seguido de "Specify SameSite=Strict or SameSite=Lax if the cookie should not be sent in cross-site requests

1 cookie
Name Domain & Path
PHPSESSID localhost/
""

Comment: El api rest lo has creado tu  o es un api rest de terceros?